# JVM shutdown hook quits unexpectedly

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

I'm doing JVM profiling for Hadoop tasks using Java agent, as in https://github.com/etsy/statsd-jvm-profiler. The profiler registers shutdown hooks, which save the profiles to HDFS. But currently the hooks are terminated before they can finish. I'm sure they are executed because I can see some outputs from the hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see any IOExceptions or FileSystem closed errors. If so, then disabling hdfs shutdown hooks can help.

Hdfs Client also registers shutdown hooks to be able to close hdfs connections properly. The order in which shutdown hooks are invoked is not guaranteed. Hdfs hooks may get invoked before others. You could try disabling shutdown hooks. It also means you will need to close the connection in your code.

To create the hdfs client instance:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setBoolean("fs.automatic.close", false);
filesystem = FileSystem.get(nnURI, conf)
```

In the shutdown hook:

```
fileSystem.close();
```

Comment: I think this is the problem. Because what I do in the hook is to write a short string to a file. But if I set fs.automatic.close to false, how do I manually close HDFS connection manually in my hook? I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to JavaDoc:

> Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly.  When a program
>   invokes exit the expectation is that the
>   virtual machine will promptly shut down and exit. ... **It is therefore inadvisable to attempt
>   any user interaction or to perform a long-running computation** in a
>   shutdown hook.

It means you have less than one second to complete your task(the exact value really depends on platform). Also worth noting that:

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may *abort*, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. ...   If the virtual machine aborts then **no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run**.